Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected! (Puppeteer + AWS Lambda + chromium)
I am trying to run the function on AWS Lambda to crawl the website to get the content.
This is my code:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");

exports.handler = async function (event) {
  const { url } = event.queryStringParameters;
  let browser = null;

  let content;
  chromium.setHeadlessMode = true;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      args: chromium.args,
    });

    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

    const selectors = [
      "article",
      "main",
      ".post",
      ".post-content",
      ".article-content",
      "#content",
      ".content",
      ".new-article",
      ".c-articleContent",
    ];
    for (let selector of selectors) {
      content = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        const element = document.querySelector(sel);
        return element ? element.innerText : null;
      }, selector);
    }
    if (content) {
      console.log(
        "------------- content of web page 2 -------------- ",
        content
      );
      await page.close();
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: content,
      };
    }

    // await browser.disconnect();
    console.error(
      `No article content found for URL: ${url} with standard selectors.`
    );
    // Return an empty string or a default message
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("--------- Error ==============", error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
    // return error;
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }
};

I am getting this error:
Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
I don't know where is the issue, I have tried every possible solution I have found on the internet but it is not working, can anyone help me out.

Which line is causing the error? Does it work if you run the code on your own computer? Some websites block the IP address range from AWS to prevent people crawling, so that might be happening.

I don't know which line is causing this issue, but I am getting the error from console inside catch. It is giving me a response but also an error as well locally, and I am trying with the same url this: https://www.simplilearn.com/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-artificial-intelligence-article

Did you solve the problem? It starts happen today for me

@dm707 No I didn't able to make it work, so I moved the code to Google Cloud Functions and it worked. I used these in package.json file:
"type": "commonjs",   "scripts": {     "start": "functions-framework --target=article",     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "dependencies": {     "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.3.0",     "puppeteer-core": "^10.1.0",     "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0"   }
my function name was article instead of handler.
I use chrome-aws-lambda instead of chromium and I am using Node 18 in gcloud function
